# Is it better to use reduce or a for loop for calculating the sum of values in an array? Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have worked out two ways of calculating the same thing in my JavaScript. I just wonder which is more efficient in terms of memory usage and processing power:

```
AveragePL = netArray.reduce((sum,arr) => sum + arr, 0);
```

or

```
for (let index in netArray) {
  AveragePL = AveragePL + netArray[index];
}
```

I realise I could do AveragePL += netArray[index] but I am new to JS, so I am using the full form so that I know what is going on for a moment.

Comment: If you are new to JS: don't `for (let index in netArray) {AveragePL = AveragePL + netArray[index];}`, do `for (let value of netArray) {AveragePL = AveragePL + value;}`. The first one scans the array for existing indices, *and* then indexes into the array, which is not just more complicated to write, but also slower than picking the values immediately.

Answer (score 1):

It would actually depend on the implementation of the JS engine.

Additionally there are different types of for loops `for..in`, `for..of` and the classic `for`

The classic for is the most optimized so it will blow all others out of the water in most implementations, including the `reduce` approach which has to execute a function for each iteration.

```
for (let i = 0, len = netArray.len; i < len; i++){
    AveragePL = AveragePL + netArray[i];
}
```

In firefox you can see the the following extended benchmark.

See https://jsben.ch/xU8Nd

Answer (score 0):

reduce is more efficent than for iterations
u can take a look at here [Why you should use reduce instead of loops](https://dev.to/babak/why-you-should-use-reduce-instead-of-loops----part-i-5dfa)

Answer (score -1):

The `.reduce()` is much faster than a loop, a reduce is always preferred over a loop if you can. Here is a test of an array of 1'000 items, repeating 10'000 times:

```js
const netArray = Array.from(Array(1000).keys());

let start = new Date();
let sumReduce;
for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  sumReduce = netArray.reduce((sum,arr) => sum + arr, 0);
}
let timeReduce = new Date() - start;

start = new Date();
let sumLoop;
for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  sumLoop = 0;
  for(let index in netArray) {
    sumLoop += netArray[index];
  }
}
let timeLoop = new Date() - start;

console.log({
  sumReduce: sumReduce,
  timeReduce: timeReduce,
  sumLoop: sumLoop,
  timeLoop: timeLoop
});
```

Output:

```
{
  "sumReduce": 499500,
  "timeReduce": 77,
  "sumLoop": 499500,
  "timeLoop": 971
}
```

Times are in msec.